# Does using Aliases with AS slow down Query Speed?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alias

If I have a T-SQL Query like the following:

```
SELECT [TableAlias].[ColumnOne] AS [Column 1]
FROM [dbo].[TableName] AS [TableAlias]
```

Will there be a performance difference if I compare the above query with this one below?

```
SELECT [TableAlias].[ColumnOne] [Column 1]
FROM [dbo].[TableName] [TableAlias]
```

Assuming the table `[dbo].[TableName]` has a lot of data in it.

Any help / insight will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the _actual execution plan_ to see what the difference is for executing the query. Compilation time may vary and could be improved by aliases since they only require a limited symbol table search to identify the data source and not a broader search ensure that it is unambiguous.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: Using _qualified_ column names, whether with the table name or an alias, can improve the performance of the compiler. Semantic analysis for a reference to `Foo` requires searching the symbol table for _all_ applicable occurrences of `Foo`. The result must be unambiguous. A reference to `Bar.Foo`, whether `Bar` is a table name or alias within the query, requires only locating `Foo` within the `Bar` entries in the symbol table. Using qualified names is a best practice and the performance penalty, if any, is outweighed by the benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all and the performance impact is negligible. Alias give you  much better time readability in the query as it removed ambiguity.

Comment: I agree that using AS in aliases improves readability. Reason I'm asking is: Another developer removed the AS in aliases of my original T-SQL, making it more difficult for me to read, so I wondered if there are performance implications.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Unless you consider the time used by the parser to read few bytes...

Comment: So if we consider the time used by the parser to read a few bytes; the performance difference would be just fractions of a second, regardless of how much data is in the table right?

Comment: Yes. Fraction of millisecond. And you have best readability, as pointed from zealous.